# Multiple button enabling

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have 9 disabled buttons.  Is there any method to enable them at once instead of doing something like this:

```
button1.Enabled=True
button2.Enabled=True
...
```

Comment: So. Is it C# or is it VB.NET? =)

Comment: From the example, I'd go with the latter

Comment: I'd say the former, since the casing is `true` in C# and `True` in VB.

Comment: I was just looking at the missing ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
foreach(Button b in Controls){
   b.Enabled = true;
}
```

Here you select all your buttons, represented by *b* and then you enabled all of of them

Hope it helps

Comment: @kushal `For Each b As Button In Controls` then your code, and then `Next`, just like in a For loop.

Comment: this could throw an error when you come across a control that isn't a button. What I've done in the past is use linq on the Controls collection to pull out all controls that are buttons. Once you have that collection you can then scroll through them all to enable/disable them. The linq would look like: `Dim tempCol = From r In Controls Where r.GetType() = GetType(Windows.Forms.Button) Select r`. then replace Controls with tempCol in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
button1.enabled = button2.enabled = ... = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've grouped them well...

```
foreach(var button in parent.Controls.OfType<Button>())
   button.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void EnableButtons(bool enabled)
{
    var myButtons = new Button[] { button1, button2, button3 };

    foreach (var x in myButtons)
    {
        x.Enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

This allows you to add and remove buttons to and from your button array as you see fit. nachogsiri's solution is great if you want to enable/disable every button on your form, if it is only certain related buttons, this gives you more control.

Answer (score 0):

Linq does it quite pretty:

```
Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(c => c.Enabled = true);
```

Comment: anonymous functions are very powerful but the OP sounds quite new so this may not make sense without more explanation.